# Сохранение ввода виселица

Tags: python

Нужно, чтобы после ввода значения сохранялись, а не исчезали.
Пример:

j---

j-v-

java

в то время как у меня

j---

--v-

-a-a

```
import random

words = ['python', 'java', 'kotlin', 'javascript']

random_ = random.choice(words)
print(random_)

random_array = list(random_)

dash = len(random_) * "-"

print(dash)


def brut_force(check):  # перебор
    for i in range(len(random_array)):

        if check == random_array[i]:
            print(check,end='')

        else:
            print("-",end='')


while True:
    print()
    check = input()
    brut_force(check)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас нигде не сохраняется результат. Как вариант можно сделать так:

```
import random

words = ['python', 'java', 'kotlin', 'javascript']

random_ = random.choice(words)
print(random_)

random_array = list(random_)

dash = list(len(random_) * "-")

print(''.join([str(elem) for elem in dash]), end='')


def brut_force(check):  # перебор
    for i in range(len(random_array)):

        if check == random_array[i]:
            dash[i] = check

    print(''.join(map(str, dash)), end='')


while True:
    print()
    check = input()
    brut_force(check)
```

Вывод:

```
java
----
j
j---
a
ja-a
v
java
```